# Terraform Cloud + OIDC AWS + assume role

Tags: terraform, openid-connect, aws-organizations, assume-role

I have 2 AWS accounts in my organization:

- `root` (main account)
- `dev` (account belongs to the organization)

I'm using GitHub + Terraform Cloud (with VCS) to deploy my infrastructure.

I have all deployments done to the `root` AWS account through Terraform Cloud and OIDC connection which works great (so my OIDC connection is setup properly).

The problem starts when I would like to create some resources in the `dev` account through assume role using `root` account.

In my `dev` account I have a proper role called `dev-admin`:

which has trust policy like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{AWS_ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID}:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and permissions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My terraform code which I would like to deploy and use looks like:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "1.6.6"

  backend "remote" {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "my-org"

    workspaces {
      name = "some-name"
    }
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 5.31.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  allowed_account_ids = ["{AWS_ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID}"]
  region              = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  allowed_account_ids = ["{AWS_DEV_ACCOUNT_ID}"]
  region              = "eu-central-1"
  alias               = "dev"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::{AWS_DEV_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/dev-admin"
  }
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "dev" {
  provider = aws.dev
}

output "ops_account_id" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.dev.account_id
}
```

> Whenever I publish this code to the my repo and Terraform Cloud detect changes and try execute this code then I'm geting:
>
> Error: Cannot assume IAM Role with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].dev on main.tf line 32, in provider "aws":
>
> IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::{AWS_DEV_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/dev-admin) cannot be assumed.
>
> There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
> The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
> The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
> The role ARN is not valid
>
> Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 12570870-2b42-45e9-a1ce-a07157dc17ca, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::{AWS_ROOT_ACCOUNT_ID}:assumed-role/terraform-cloud-oidc/terraform-run-ZsGi3xVXjuYKiKC4 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::{AWS_DEV_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/dev-admin

Any ideas how it can be solved?

Comment: I think what you are missing here is that you don't need the second provider block. By allowing the role to be assumed from the "root" provider configuration you are telling terraform that it can perform actions in the secondary ("dev") account.

Comment: Can you try to run `aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/dev-admin" --role-session-name AWSCLI-Session` locally to see if the credentials are correct?

Comment: I need the second provider block (with assume_role - the `dev` alias) because I would like to create some resources in that account. But My OIDC connection between Terraform Cloud and AWS is pointing to my `root` account. The first provider (without alias) of course I can skip but it not change anything. 

Regarding the cli command of course it works because I execute it using my personal credentials (saved in .aws/credentials). 

So again I think the problem is correlated with TF Cloud and OIDC connection. 
Now the question is how to solve it?